# why the function f is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone explain why the piecewise constant function $f:[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$f(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & t\in[0,1/2] \\
      1 & t\in(1/2,1] \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

is Riemann integrable?

I have shown that the sequence $f_n\in C_\mathbb{R}[0,1]$, defined by

$f_n(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0, & t\in[0,1/2] \\
      n(t-1/2), & t\in[1/2,1/2 + 1/n] \\
      1, & t\in[1/2 +1/n,1] \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

tends pointwise to $f(t)$ in $[0,1]$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and now I want an explanation why $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Does the question require you to use the fact about $f_n$ is integrable? I think it is easier to show $f$ is Darboux integrable directly.

Comment: No it doesn't, but I've said what I've done before in case it is needed. What do you mean by ''Darboux integrable''? I haven't heard it before.

Comment: I think this time the sequence may not be very useful indeed because we do not have uniform convergence. Darboux integrability deals with the so-called upper integral and the lower integral and it is equivalent to Riemann integrability.

Comment: Yeah I know it is not very useful.. but if you think of something please feel free to comment it.

Comment: You can prove that a bounded function discontinuous at most countably many points is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question about Riemann integrability is Lebesgue criteria for Riemann integrability:

> A function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and discontinuous on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: So the explanation to this is that $f$ is discontinuous and bounded?

Comment: @P.D.: your function is Riemann integrable since it is bounded and discontinuous on a set of measure $0$ (discontinuous at the point $x=1/2$).

Comment: what do you mean by a set of measure 0?

Comment: @P.D.: This comes from measure theory which I do not think you have studied it yet. However your set of discontinuity $\left\{ 0\right\}$ has measure $0$ since it s countable. But at least you have studied that if the function is bounded and has a finite number of discontinuities then it is Riemann integrable,

Comment: I think it is even more advanced than Darboux integrability. Probably OP just knows the concept and basic properties of Riemann integrability.

Comment: @SRX: I already gave him an alternative answer in my last comment.